# Getting chef.exceptions.ChefServerError: Method Not Allowed while creating Role in chef

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I am trying to create a role using PyChef api. I am able to retrieve list of nodes or roles (GET method) successfully but when i m trying to create a role (POST method) i am  getting an runtime excetion, i.e, method not allowed.
Here is my code :

```
import json
import requests
import re
import chef
from chef.exceptions import ChefError, ChefServerNotFoundError
from chef.base import ChefQuery, ChefObject
from chef import Role

pem_file = "path-to-validator.pem/chef-validator.pem"
client_name = "validator"
node_name = "root"
role_url = "ChefServer-URL/roles/"
rolelist =[]

chef_api = chef.ChefAPI(role_url,pem_file,client_name,ssl_verify=False)

create_role = chef.Role.create(name='myrole', api=chef_api ,description='A test role', run_list=['recipe[foo]'],default_attributes={'attr': 'foo'}, override_attributes={'attr': 'bar'})

rolelst = chef.Role.list()
for j in rolelst:
  rolelist.append(j)
print rolelist
```

And here is the error that i am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "roleapi.py", line 37, in <module>
create_role = chef.Role.create(name='myrole', api=chef_api ,description='A 
test role', run_list=['recipe[foo]'],default_attributes={'attr': 'foo'}, 
override_attributes={'attr': 'bar'})
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/chef/base.py", line 99, in create
api.api_request('POST', cls.url, data=obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 217, in 
api_request
response = self.request(method, path, headers, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 207, in request
raise ChefServerError.from_error(response.reason, code=response.status_code)
chef.exceptions.ChefServerError: Method Not Allowed
```

So please suggest me something how can i resolve this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a user and its key and not the validator client, its role is to register new nodes, it doesn't have authorization to create anything else than nodes and clients.

Comment: @Tensibai : Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried your suggestion (use user and its key in place of validator client) but it still gives me same error.

Comment: And there's no role named myrole already existing ? (a POST on an existing object won't work, you'll have to do a PUT)

Comment: @Tensibai : Yeah this role does not pre-exist. Its a new one.

Comment: Could you give the form used for ChefServer-URL ? it should be https://server_name/organizations/NAME/roles accodring to the server API documentation: https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#id66

Comment: Yes, i am using the recommended url structure.. i.e, https://server_fqdn/organizations/NAME/roles

Comment: you will have to dig into your server logs then `chef-server-ctl tail` could be a good start if there's not too much activity on your server

Comment: @Tensibai : thank you so much.. Your suggestions work.. my code works successfully now.. Thank u so much ..

Answer (score 2):

The URL should be the base of the Chef Server, probably something like `https://myserver.com/organizations/foo`.